# Como hago para que los nombres de la lista sean mostrandos sin corchetes y sin '?

Tags: python

Al mostrar los nombres aleatorios de la lista estos son mostrados como por ejemplo "['Lina']", como logro que no se muestren esos corchetes y esa '?

```
def main():
import random
lEstudiantes=["Lina","Ana","Felipe","Tola","Carola","Catalina","Hector","Luis","Lorna","Tere","Juan","Jonier"]
Cant_Estud_Elegidos=int(input("Ingrese la cantidad de estudiantes que desea que aporten a la alcancia: "))
while Cant_Estud_Elegidos==0 or Cant_Estud_Elegidos>=12:
 Cant_Estud_Elegidos=int(input("Ingrese de nuevo la cantidad de estudiantes que desea que aporten a la alcancia, no puede ser mayor a 12 ni menor a 1: "))
Estud_Elegidos=random.sample(lEstudiantes, Cant_Estud_Elegidos)
print("Los estudiantes que haran el aporte son:",Estud_Elegidos)
```

main()

Comment: No imprimas la lista. Itera por ella con un bucle for e imprime cada elemento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si quieres controlar al detalle la presentación, tienes que imprimir cada elemento por separado.

```
print("Los estudiantes que haran el aporte son:")
for estudiante in Estud_Elegidos:
    print(estudiante)
```

Si imprimes una lista (`Estud_Elegidos`, por ejemplo), la salida **debe** mostrar que es una lista; por eso muestra los `[]`. Como es una lista, debe mostrar cada elemento de acuerdo a su tipo. Eso explica las cremillas, que te indican que el elemento es un string. Asi no confundes el string "1" con el valor entero 1:

```
["1", 1]  # Es una lista de dos elementos, un string y un entero.
```

Si imprimes un elemento por separado, Python te mostrará el contenido sin más.

**Demo**

```
import random


def main():
    lEstudiantes = ["Lina", "Ana", "Felipe", "Tola", "Carola", "Catalina", "Hector", "Luis", "Lorna", "Tere", "Juan",
                    "Jonier"]
    Cant_Estud_Elegidos = int(input("Ingrese la cantidad de estudiantes que desea que aporten a la alcancia: "))
    while Cant_Estud_Elegidos == 0 or Cant_Estud_Elegidos >= 12:
        Cant_Estud_Elegidos = int(input(
            "Ingrese de nuevo la cantidad de estudiantes que desea que aporten a la alcancia, no puede ser mayor a 12 ni menor a 1: "))
    Estud_Elegidos = random.sample(lEstudiantes, Cant_Estud_Elegidos)
    print("Los estudiantes que haran el aporte son:")
    for estudiante in Estud_Elegidos:
        print(estudiante)


main()
```

produce:

```
Ingrese la cantidad de estudiantes que desea que aporten a la alcancia: 4
Los estudiantes que haran el aporte son:
Tola
Juan
Carola
Hector

Process finished with exit code 0
```